# VBA Reducing time complexity of nested for-loop

Tags: vba, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have 2 Collections (Collection A, Collection B) and every object in A has to compare itself with EVERY object in B (cannot exit early). Unfortunately this causes an O(n^2) complexity. Keep in mind, both A and B are very large (1000+).

My question is: are there any alternative ways to go about this? Also does VBA have a simple built in function which deals with this?

Comment: Well if it *must* compare every value,  it *must* compare every value.  There is nothing built in to do this.

Comment: There are some ways you could speed this up - for example, performing a sort first. There are pre-made custom macros which do this; I thought ozgrid.com had a full suite of 'array comparison' macros, but it doesn't seem to. Perhaps they've moved that package to the pay-site.

Comment: Are they collections of custom objects, strings, ints, doubles?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "compare"... if your simply looking for equality for example, a simper inner join will find items in A that are also in B.  If you mean you need to perform an operation or evaluate a function... then the optimization will depend entirely on the function.  So you're question is too vague as it stands.

Comment: You can use the Exists function of the Scripting.Dictionary, or try to put the value in to collection B and trap the error, so if B accepts the value of A, then its NOT in B, if it doesnt then it is already in col B.

Comment: How long does it take with your current code?  Is that too slow?

Comment: This is a lot of questions to answer so i'll try my best:

-This is a collection of custom objects (each object is a class containing strings and long variable)

-The long variables in each object is a range (long x for min and long y for max, together they form a range). Both Collection (A and B) have the same object. So I'm comparing the range overlap, i.e if range(x,y) of collection A overlaps with range(x,y) of collection B then add that object from collection A to a new collection.

Comment: -This whole process takes about 1 hour to complete. However while testing it, after iterating through 500 indexes from Collection A, it just freezes. In this case Collection A has 28000 indexes, collection B has 5800. So for every Collection A index, it`ll need to iterate through 5800 objects. I`m aware these are large numbers but I don't think it should've froze.